# What services does Nagios notify per contact?

Tags: nagios, contacts

In Nagios 3.2.3, I'd like to see all the hosts/services that send notifications to a specific contact.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I can answer my own question after a bit more googling.  In the Nagios Support forums, I found this answer:

https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10329

It is pretty much exactly what I was looking for.
I hope this can help someone else someday.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the tip Zoredache.
The link says you can 'cat' and 'grep' Nagios's objects.cache file to get the items you need from the running config.  From the link I used:

```
cat /usr/local/nagios/var/objects.cache | grep 'host_name\|service_description\|contacts\|notification_period' |grep -v command_name | sed 's/host_name/\n/g' > /tmp/contacts.txt
```

to get a list that I then ran through to pull the config items I wanted for the report.
It exports like:

```
Server1
service_description     Linux Raid Status checks /proc/mdstat
contacts        sysadmin
notification_period     24x7

Server1
service_description     Web Server Port 80 check
contacts        sysadmin,developers
notification_period     24x7
```

I hope this helps someone else, and thanks for the tip again Zoredache.

Comment: Answers on serverfault really should be more then just a link to a forum that may die.  You should at least minimally summarize what you found on the link, that way in the future people can possibly find a relocated page through a search.

Comment: @Zoredache the answer has been edited and extended, you can upvote now :)